# Class of Polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Define a set $\pi=\lbrace p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_{2n}\rbrace$ where $p_i\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, and $p_i\leq D$. Define a class of polynomials $\mathcal{P}$ of the form $p(x_1,\ldots,x_{2n})=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i^{p_i}-\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{2n} x_i^{p_i}$. Note that the coefficients of the monomials are restricted to $\lbrace -1,1\rbrace$, and the total degree of the polynomial cannot exceed $D$.

Can we say anything about the behavior of these polynomials over $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$? I'm especially interested in obtaining bounds on  $|Z(p)|$, the size of the zero set of $p$.

Comment: Do they all cross the origin?

Comment: where $Z(p)$ is ...?

Comment: You may as well replace all the $p_i$ with $1$ or $2$ depending on whether they are odd or even. So say $x-y^2$ would be an example of such a polynomial. Still, unclear what you are asking for.